# Is there a built in alternative to BottomNavigationBar but for a bottom menu?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and am building my first app. I have a small app with maybe 4 pages, there is a bottom bar which has icons on it. Some icons call functions such as copy text (which does not need its own page but is a function to be called) while others are complex and call a new page using `Navigator.push()`.

I tried to achieve this using a custom `Row()` widget on each page, but it became very odd and I was rewriting a lot of functions. I felt there had to be a bottom menu bar, but couldn't find one.

I found `BottomNavigationBar` and was excited that it would achieve what I wanted. But I don't think its meant to be used as a menu, but rather as the name implies, a navigation bar.

I also want the navigation bar to change menu icons as it moves to a new page. The tutorial I am following uses it as follows:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.white),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepOrange),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.green)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Bottem Navi '),
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text('Search'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('Profile')
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The `body:` is changed based on the index selected. Can this be repurposed to act as a menu? to make use of `Navigator.push` or is my previous method of having a `Row()` widget on each page the best option?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a function called `showModalBottomSheet()`. You can check it out [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html).

Comment: As for using `Navigator.push()`; Yeah, u can do that whenever an icon is clicked.  And set the body to `PlaceholderWidget(Colors.white)`. Put the `_children` widgets in a new file and so, when you're in a new screen, u can refer that file and push that page using `Navigator.push()` whenever a new icon is selected in that bottom menu. Also, I'd recommend using `Navigator.pushReplacement()` to avoid memory leaks. If ya still don't get it, I'll post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `BottomAppBar` 
code snippet

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()));
              },
            ),
            Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.title),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Show Snackbar'),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                        ));
                      },
                    )),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Tasks - Bottom App Bar')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[500],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[100],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()));
              },
            ),
            Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.title),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Show Snackbar'),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                        ));
                      },
                    )),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.sync),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed answer. I'm sorry to bother again, but is there any way to add text under each icon, similar to the ``title:`` tag in ``BottomNavigationBarItem()``. I tried adding the title by wrapping the Icon in a ``column()`` and adding a ``Text()`` widget to it, but that broke the full layout and the ``BottomNavBar()`` took the full screen.

Comment: You can use SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                color: Colors.orange,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.add),
                    Text("Add")
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

Comment: You can change height per your request.